# Объявление множества массивов через цикл

Tags: java

мне нужно находить конечную разность от Y, для этого я использую массивы. Можно ли как то объявлять массивы через цикл, или какая альтернатива может быть?
По формуле ΔY = Yi+1-Yi. Так как количество значений Y может быть любым, приходится использовать много массивов. Подскажите, как реализовать для любого количества значения Y. Для определенного количества значений я реализовал это так:

```java
    double[] y = {1.6990, 1.7404,1.7782,1.8129};
    double[] detY = new double [3];
    double[] detY2 = new double [2];
    double[] detY3 = new double [1];

    //находим первую конечную разность
    for (int  i = 0; i<y.length-1;i++ )
      {
        detY[i] +=Math.round(( y[i+1]-y[i])*10000.0)/10000.0;
        System.out.println(detY[i]);
        if(i == y.length - 1) break;
       }
        System.out.println("==============");

        //находим вторую конечную разность
        for (int  i = 0; i<detY.length-1;i++ )
          {
            detY2[i] += Math.round((detY[i+1]-detY[i])*10000.0)/10000.0;
             System.out.println(detY2[i]);
             if(i == detY.length - 1) break;
          }
         System.out.println("==============");

         //находим третью конечную разность
         for (int  i = 0; i<detY2.length-1;i++ )
           {
             detY3[i] += Math.round((detY2[i+1]-detY2[i])*10000.0)/10000.0;
             System.out.println(detY3[i]);
             if(i == detY2.length - 1) break;
           }
```

Comment: Двумерный треугольный массив, длины строк уменьшаются.

Answer (score 0):

Как по мне, то это классическая задача на рекурсию.

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {

    private final static NumberFormat FORMATTER = new DecimalFormat("#0.0000");

    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        double[] y = {1.6990, 1.7404, 1.7782, 1.8129};
        double[] det = calcFiniteDifference(y);
        //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(det));
    }

    private static double[] calcFiniteDifference (double[] det){
        if (det.length==1) return det;
        double[] detY = new double[det.length-1];
        for (int i = 0; i < det.length-1; i++) detY[i] = det[i+1] - det[i];
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(detY));
        System.out.println("==============");
        return calcFiniteDifference(detY);
    }

}
```

Если нужно только последнее значение, то вывод нужно перенести в метод мейн. Заодно покажу, как избавиться от создания большого количества массивов. Обратите внимание на форматер. Именно он обеспечивает нужный формат вывода в консоль (делить на 10000, округлять и потом умножать на 10000 не есть хорошо)

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.NumberFormat;

public class Main {

    private final static NumberFormat FORMATTER = new DecimalFormat("#0.0000");

    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        double[] y = {1.6990, 1.7404, 1.7782, 1.8129};
        double[] det = calcFiniteDifference(y, y.length);
        System.out.println(FORMATTER.format(det[0]));
    }

    private static double[] calcFiniteDifference (double[] det, int arrSize){        
        if (arrSize<=1) return det;
        for (int i = 0; i < det.length-1; i++) det[i] = det[i+1] - det[i];
        return calcFiniteDifference(det, arrSize-1);
    }

}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Мне после нахождения конечных разностей, необходимо подставить их в формулу 1/h*(detY[i]-(detY2[i]/2)+ detY3[i]/3) -...+detYN[i]/3)
где h = шаг значений Х; i = номер Х, которого нужно найти
Для того чтобы найти производную. Т.е у меня есть таблица со значениями Х и У, и в 3 колонке я вывожу производную для Х. И я не могу понять как мне сделать ее универсальной для любого количества значений, хоть для 1000. Я в самом начале не до конца изложил суть своей задачи. И я до конца не понял из вашего второго кода как избавиться от создания большого количества массивов

Comment: я не вижу в вашей задаче этой формулы 1/h*(detY[i]-(detY2[i]/2)+ detY3[i]/3) -...+detYN[i]/3). вы написали, что решили задачу для конкретного количества значений. результат работы вашей программы-0,0005. аналогичный результат дает второе решение, при этом никаких массивов не создается. все решается в пределах 1 массива.первое решение может вывести тоже самое, что и ваш код,используя рекурсию.т.е.ваш первоначальный массив может быть любой длины и все будет работать. о том, что вам еще что-то нужно подставить в формулу вы не писали, ваше решение этого тоже не предусматривает.посему и ответ такой

Comment: решите задачу до конца с органиченным количеством аргументов. надо понимать, что именно вы хотите получить на выходе. это одно число или массив чисел? 1/h*(detY[i]-(detY2[i]/2)+ detY3[i]/3) -...+detYN[i]/3) - в этой формуле под массивом detY3 понимается созданный вами массив detY3? зачем тогда 2 остальных массива? h = шаг значений  - как это понять?